# Inserting into a oracle table using Where condition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I am new to write queries in oracle. I want to insert a row in a table using where condition of another table

For example : I have two tables: Table1 and Table2

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) values ('1', '2', '3') 
            where exists (select * from table2 where col2 = '2')
```

Can i have a query like this? is there any syntax error, please correct me. Basically,, i want to insert a row into table one, if the table2 has a row with `col2 = '2'`.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Suggested way causes syntax error.

It's suitable to use in this way (for such an aim) :

```
insert into table1 (col2)
select col2 from table2 where col2 = '2';
```

or

```
insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3 from table2 where col2 = '2';
```

or maybe(depending on the second table's data)

```
insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3 from table2 where (col1,col2,col3) in ('1','2','3');
```

provided both table has at least these columns(col1,col2,col3).

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you only need to compare if the `col2` of `TABLE2` should be '2', or you expect the `col2` of `TABLE2` to be same as the value of `COL2` used for insertion.

If it is only about `'2'`, you could use this.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(col1,col2,col3)  select '1', '2', '3'  FROM DUAL 
WHERE EXISTS ( select 1 FROM TABLE2 WHERE col2 = '2' );
```

If it is about `col2` in general, then you could use:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(col1,col2,col3) 
                               with d(col1,col2,col3) AS 
                                             ( select '1' , '2' , '5' FROM DUAL )
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM d                                     
         WHERE EXISTS ( select 1 FROM TABLE2 t WHERE t.col2 = d.col2 );
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c6998/1)

Comment: @user3145999 : SO users say thanks by upvoting, marking answer as correct - ✓ or both